# UML Data Modeller which generates SQL?

Tags: data-modeling, uml, erd, tool-uml

I have been using ERD programs for a while now to: generate to, or reverse engineer from, my database.

However I recently learned the UML syntax equivalent, and am looking for an "IDE" that can generate SQL (and reverse-engineer from) my db. I am using Oracle 11g.

Preferably a free tool, if you know of one.

Comment: "my db" seems to reference a UML tool. Please let us know which one. Also it is important to know which type system your are using or intending to use for your UML. The generation and reverse engineering otherwise could be pretty straightforward and can be done with a few lines of code if your UML model uses the database type system (e.g. VARCHAR) - i could supply an example then based on one of the tools. If the types need to be converted e.g. from a programming language like Java or if you need a platform independent type system the tasks is a bit more tricky.

Comment: I recently generated SQL from my UML models using GenMyModel. It's a browser-hosted UML modeler, free. The code was generated from class diagrams and helped me boostrap my db. At the moment, no option for the sql generation and no reverse.

Comment: Thanks, keep me in the loop for when it supports those features.